The answer is a highly composite number
This is part 6, see for part 5: This puzzle is delicious

The answer is a highly composite number.



1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th













Each picture

can be described by a word that has an antonym.

The pictures depict

FULL (EMPTY)
LOSE (WIN)
DARK (LIGHT)
LEFT (RIGHT)
HEAVY (LIGHT)

which gives the answer

FORTY-EIGHT, a highly composite number.


That's amazing. I was expecting to get the next higher number since that's the only one that fit.

Correct! When creating this puzzle, the following were also possible: #2 groom-bride (3), #5 dry-wet (3), but I really liked it this way, how it turned out to be 1,2,3,4,5 :)
